# Refinement of Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, divisor-sum, prime-gaps

Bertrand's Postulate states that "for all $n \geq 2$, there is a prime $p$ between $n$ and $2n-2$". So a consequence is that, for all $n \geq 2$, there exists a prime $p \in (n, 2n)$.

Let be $\delta: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ the function defined by $\delta(1) = 0$, and $\delta(n) = p_1 + \ldots + p_r$ if $n = p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_r$ is the canonical prime descomposition of $n$. For example $\delta(20) = \delta(2^2 \cdot 5) = 2 + 2 + 5 = 9$, $\delta(p) = p$ for all primes $p$.

Define $n$ is *refined* is there is a prime in the interval $(n, n + \delta(n))$. Otherwise we say that $n$ is *unrefined*. I choose this name because $n$ improves, refines, the Bertrand Postulate. The first unrefined number is 5120.

[Chebyshev theorem](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate.html) states that for all $\epsilon > 0 \in \mathbb(R)$, there is $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, there is a prime number $p$ in the interval $(n, n+\epsilon n)$. Chebyshev theorem is consequence of Prime Number Theorem.

Consequence to Chebyshev theorem, it's easy to see that if $(i_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence of unrefined numbers, $\delta(i_n)/i_n$ tends to $0$. So, for every fixed $m \geq 1$, there is just a finite unrefined numbers in the set $I_m = \{m\cdot p \, | \, p \text{ primer number} \}$. Note that $I_1$ is the set of prime numbers.

I have two questions:

- are unrefined numbers finite?
- where is the counting function of unrefined numbers? That is, if we define $\Pi(x) = |\{ n \text{ unrefined } | n \leq x \}|$, how is $\Pi(x)$?

I conjecture that unrefined numbers are infinite but its counting function is very low.

This question is connected with [Sierpinski conjecture](https://www.primepuzzles.net/conjectures/conj_026.htm): For any $n\geq 2$ and any $1 < k \leq n$ there exists a prime number between $(k-1)n$ and $kn$.

This question is also related to [Legendre's conjecture](https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Legendre's_conjecture.html): there is a prime between $n$ and $n^2$. When $n=p$, $n$ is refined if, and only if, $n$ satisfies Legendre's conjecture.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence – it is certainly not true that there is always a prime between $2s$ and $2(s+1)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry. I edit the question because original Sierpinski conjecture had no constraints.

Comment: it actually states there's a prime between n and 2n-2

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What states there's a prime between $n$ and $2n-2$?

Comment: Bertrans postulate. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate  first paragraph.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Edit question for clarificate this

Comment: Your function $\delta$ is called $\Omega(n) = \sum_{p^k \| n} k p$. The proportion of $n$ such that $\Omega(n) \le 2 \ln^2 n$ is very low (something like $\frac{\log N}{N}$) under Cramer's conjecture $\Omega(n) > 2\ln^2 n$ implies $\pi(n+  \Omega(n))  > \pi(n)$. Thus under Cramer I'd say it is very likely that there finitely many $n$ such that $\pi(n+\Omega(n)) = \pi(n)$.

Comment: @reuns all primes 4 and 6 force Bertands postulate either way.

Comment: @reuns Can you give some references for $\Omega(n)$? Thanks. Can you so, provide some sort of answer. What happens if Cramer's conjecture is false?

Comment: Here is the sequence $\delta(n)$ in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A001414.